# multiple types of input with Sweetaleart2

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I am trying to get values from multiple inputs using Sweetalert2 created with html.

```
swal({
      type: 'question',
      title: 'Confirm recipient details',
      html: '<p style="color:#C00; padding-bottom:0px; margin-bottom:0px">
            Cloud only terms and conditions</p>
             <div class="swal_input_wrapper">
             <div class="label_wrapper">Email: </div>
               <input id="swal-input1" style="width:75%" class="swal2-input" autofocus><br/>
             <div class="label_wrapper">Recipient: </div>
               <input id="swal-input2" style="width:75%" class="swal2-input"></div><br/>
             <div class="label_wrapper">Message: </div>
               <textarea id="swal-input3" style="width:75%" class="swal2-textarea"></textarea>
             </div>',
              preConfirm: function() {
                   return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                        resolve([
                            $('#swal-input1').val(),
                            $('#swal-input2').val(),
                            $('#swal-input3').text()
                         ]);
                    });
              }
       }).then(function(result) {
          //values from inputs (results is an array)
          email = result[0];
          email_name = result[1];
          email_message = result[2];
          alert(email_name);
    }).done();
```

Testing the output as I have added parts it all works until I add 'email_message = result[2];' which would suggest it can't resolve the value of the textarea.  I have tried using the following to get the text from the textarea, all with no success...

```
$('#swal-input3').text()
$('#swal-input3').val()
$('#swal-input3').html()
```

Up until the point I add that line the alert(email_name) works but afterwards it stops with no errors or warnings that I can find.

Please note that the html portion of the above does not have line breaks in my script, I added them to try and make my code easier to read because the code section here doesn't seem to support wordwrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#swal-input3').val()` works just fine: **[[JSFIDDLE]](https://jsfiddle.net/7nhzeujs/1/)**

`.val()` is what you need to get the value of a textarea field.